# Slurm compute node on Hyper-V virtual machine, request RAM from Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, slurm

I'm trying to run slurm compute node on a virtual machine, managed by HyperV.
The node runs Ubuntu 16.04.

`slurmd -C` shows:

```
NodeName=calc1 CPUs=48 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=48 ThreadsPerCore=1 RealMemory=16013
UpTime=5-20:51:31
```

That is not absolute true, maximum amount of RAM, available to that machine, is 96Gb, but RAM is allocated by HyperV on request. If no load, the node has only 16 Gb.

I've tried running some python scripts processing big datasets, without slurm, and have seen increase of maximum RAM to 96Gb.

I've got the following in my `slurmd.conf` (among other lines):

```
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU_Memory
FastSchedule=1

DefMemPerCPU=2048
NodeName=calc1 CPUs=48 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=48 ThreadsPerCore=1 RealMemory=96000 CoreSpecCount=8 MemSpecLimit=6000
```

However, `htop` shows that only 8 cores are loaded, and 40 are idle. And Mem is only 16Gb.

Sometimes nodes fall to `Drained` state because of "Low real memory". 
Looks like slurmd does not believe to what I've written in `slurm.conf`

How can I make slurmd to request other gigabytes of RAM?

*UPDATE*

I still haven't applied config changes, proposed by @Carles Fenoy, but have observed a strange detail.

Output of `scontrol show node`:

```
NodeName=calc1 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=48
   CPUAlloc=40 CPUErr=0 CPUTot=48 CPULoad=10.25
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=(null)
   NodeAddr=calc1 NodeHostName=calc1 Version=17.11
   OS=Linux 4.4.0-145-generic #171-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 26 12:43:40 UTC 2019
   RealMemory=96000 AllocMem=81920 FreeMem=179 Sockets=1 Boards=1
   CoreSpecCount=8 CPUSpecList=40-47 MemSpecLimit=6000
   State=MIXED ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=main
   BootTime=2019-04-12T12:50:39 SlurmdStartTime=2019-04-18T09:24:29
   CfgTRES=cpu=48,mem=96000M,billing=48
   AllocTRES=cpu=40,mem=80G
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```

Then I ssh to calc1 and issue `free -h`. Here its output:

```
~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         14G        172M        520K        1.1G         77M
Swap:           15G        644M         15G
```

*UPDATE 2*
I've discussed this issue with our infrastructure specialist, and have figured out that this mechanism is called [Hyper-V Dynamic Memory](https://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/Microsoft-Hyper-V-Dynamic-Memory)

Will try to find if Microsoft provides any APIs to virtual machines. May be I'll be lucky, and someone has developed slurm plugin for it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `FastSchedule` parameter to either `0` or `2`.

This is the excerpt from the slurm.conf documentation:

> ```
>    FastSchedule
>           Controls  how a node's configuration specifications in slurm.conf are used.  If the number of node configuration entries in the configuration file is significantly lower than the number of nodes, setting FastSchedule
>           to 1 will permit much faster scheduling decisions to be made.  (The scheduler can just check the values in a few configuration records instead of possibly thousands of  node  records.)   Note  that  on  systems  with
>           hyper-threading, the processor count reported by the node will be twice the actual processor count.  Consider which value you want to be used for scheduling purposes.
>
>           0    Base  scheduling  decisions  upon the actual configuration of each individual node except that the node's processor count in Slurm's configuration must match the actual hardware configuration if PreemptMode=sus-
>                pend,gang or SelectType=select/cons_res are configured (both of those plugins maintain resource allocation information using bitmaps for the cores in the system and must remain static, while  the  node's  memory
>                and disk space can be established later).
>
>           1 (default)
>                Consider the configuration of each node to be that specified in the slurm.conf configuration file and any node with less than the configured resources will be set to DRAIN.
>
>           2    Consider the configuration of each node to be that specified in the slurm.conf configuration file and any node with less than the configured resources will not be set DRAIN.  This option is generally only useful
>                for testing purposes.
> ```